# Validate date input using given pattern - JS / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-hooks, momentjs

How to approach a problem to validate date using given date format, for example I wanted to give any date format to a component like:

`<Input format={"DD-MM-YYYY"} />`
or
`<Input format={"YYYY-MM-DD"} />`
or
`<Input format={"MM/DD/YYYY"} />`

I was trying to use combination of moment() but it was giving me true while my date wasn't finished during typing. I have to validate input date after the whole given format is typed in.

Comment: You mean you want to bind the validation after the string has been entered? If so you want to bind it to `onblur`. But I am not 100% sure if that is what you are asking

Comment: Binding is piece of cake. I was asking about is there any kinda easy way to validate string based on given pattern. Let's say, string is valid when it's meet the criteria in format prop.

Comment: You could try using regular expressions

Comment: I know, but I wanted to not use em

Comment: You want to validate the input, as it is entered, based on 3 or more patterns? But you don't want to use Regex? Surely this means that various patterns will fit your criteria, but how will you know if the user is entering date, month or year?

Comment: Using reg expressions is the best way to define and match any pattern whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is lightweight lodash like utility functions library for dates.

[isMatch](https://date-fns.org/v2.17.0/docs/isMatch) is suitable to find if date matches given format.

you can install it with npm or yarn

```
npm install date-fns --save
# or
yarn add date-fns
```

and use isMatch as

```
import isMatch from 'date-fns/isMatch'

isMatch('02/11/2014', 'MM/dd/yyyy') // true
```

*Regex can also do the job, but you need to do heavy lifting on it and maintain it.*

Comment: I never used date-fns, is it good? It has a lot of installs so I think it is a prob a good option

Comment: It has most required commonly used utils/functionality for dates including support for internationalisation, cross browser supports, documentation etc. It is better than moment js as it has FP functions. I would prefer to offload heavy lifting to tested library wherever possible.

Comment: nice, I might try it out in the future, if I may ask, what do you mean with heavy lifting (on regexes)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using regular expressions, the regular expression for a date in format DD-MM-YYYY is:

`^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$`

Now test the input against the regular expression:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // regex for DD-MM-YYYY
    const regexddmmyyyy = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;

    if (regexddmmyyyy.test(date)) {
      setValid(true);
    } else {
      setValid(false);
    }
  }, [date]);

  const handleChanged = (e) => {
    setDate(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChanged} />
      <p>{date}</p>
      {valid ? <p>Valid</p> : <p>Invalid</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-andras-xfbo6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe this provides the most flexibility of formatting and solves issues like "01" getting parsed incorrectly as a date.  It's also much more readable than Regex.  Thoughts?

moment(value, ["MM-DD-YYYY", "M-DD-YYYY", "MM-D-YYYY", "M-D-YYYY", "MM-DD-YY", "M-DD-YY", "MM-D-YY", "M-D-YY", "YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-M-DD", "YYYY-MM-D", "YYYY-M-D", "MM/DD/YYYY", "M/DD/YYYY", "MM/D/YYYY", "M/D/YYYY", "MM/DD/YY", "M/DD/YY", "MM/D/YY", "M/D/YY", "YYYY/MM/DD", "YYYY/M/DD", "YYYY/MM/D", "YYYY/M/D"], true).isValid()

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.